# postgresql to_char an integer with German format

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, to-char

I'm looking to format a float so that it will be displayed in the following way:

```
999.999.990,00
```

I'm currently using the `to_char` function:

`to_char(SUM(amount::float)/100, '999G999G990D00')`

However this format is showing commas instead of dots. Such is the standard in Germany.

When I changed the `G` (used to symbolize a comma) to a `D` (used to symbolize a dot) I get the following error:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: multiple decimal points

I'm running PostgreSQL and Psycopg2 with Python 2.7.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this replace?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following

```
TO_CHAR(SUM(amount::float)/100,'FM99G999G990D00L')
```

It should give you the following results

```
55.123.854.547,10
3.123,58
-1.257.487,90
```